# visio stencil for Handdrawing web Mockup

Tags: visio, prototyping, sketching

Can any one suggest me a hand drawn/sketch formatted Visio stencil? i.e. One that looks like a hand drawn sketch. I have seen some Web UI wire frame done using some hand drawn tool which looks very much impressive when we can present the UI sketch to the Client rather than real hand drawn sketch.

It's will be really helpful if someone can suggest a tool rather than suggesting pencil and paper is the tool which I am using right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have pretty complete list here: 
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools

Answer (score 3):

Try [GUUUI Web Prototyping Tools](http://web.archive.org/web/20120621213310/http://www.guuui.com/issues/02_07.php). It contains stencils for sketch and minimalist shapes.

Comment: Sites die. The wayback machine remembers: http://web.archive.org. I'll have pity on you and update the link ;)

Comment: The wayback machine. My new friend :)

Comment: The site's now been taking off thanks to robots.txt, which for some reason archive.org pays attention to. Feels bad man.

Comment: For the lazy
http://web.archive.org/web/20070510153220/http://www.guuui.com/issues/02_07.php